# Enter-PSSession: receiving access denied on non domain remote server

Tags: powershell, remote-access, windows-server-2022

I am struggling to open a remote PS session on a remote server (Windows Server 2022 Standard). The remote server is *not* part of a domain.

When running the command

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server01 -Credential server01\administrator
```

I receive "Access is denied".

What I have done:

- server

  - `Enable-PSRemoting`
  - `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server`
- client

  - `` Add-Content -Path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts -Value "`n192.168.1.250`tserver01" ``
  - `winrm quickconfig`
  - `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value server01`

When executing on client

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server01 -Credential server01\administrator
```

and entering the password I receive:

> Enter-PSSession : Beim Verbinden mit dem Remoteserver "server01" ist
> folgender Fehler aufgetreten: Zugriff verweigert Weitere Informationen
> finden Sie im Hilfethema "about_Remote_Troubleshooting". In Zeile:1
> Zeichen:1
> + Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server01 -Credential server01\administrator
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (server01:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

When executing on the client

```
winrm identify -r:http://server01:5985 -u:server01\Administrator -p:secret
```

I receive

> WSManFault
> Message = Zugriff verweigert
>
> Fehlernummer:  -2147024891 0x80070005 Zugriff verweigert

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

In winrm config I set `Auth/Basic` and `AllowUnencrypted` to `true` (both client and service) - same result. I then [configured HTTPS access](http://woshub.com/powershell-remoting-over-https/) with a self signed certificate - same result.

As there is no entry in `Microsoft-Windows-Windows Remote Management/Operational` on server side it looks like the request is blocked on client side. `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName server01 -Port 5985` succeeds (as it does with port 5986).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I simply had to add `-Authentication Basic` to the `Enter-PSSession` command.

Full command:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server01 -Authentication Basic -Credential administrator
```

When using `winrm identify` I had to add `-auth:basic`:

```
winrm identify -r:http://server01:5985 -a:basic -u:Administrator -p:secret
```

It was that simple ...

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using non domain useres my first guess would be that `UAC` might be blocking you.

I'd say this error is raised by the client so first try with disabled `UAC` on the client. If this does not work disbale `UAC` on the server.

If it is not `UAC` related I could imagine that this local admin account needs to be member of the `Remote Management Users` group on the server.

At least that's what I'd try next.

Comment: Unfortunately neither disabling UAC nor adding user to `Remote Management Users` group did help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the output of `winrm get winrm/config` on the server. Using Basic authentication over HTTP *sends the credentials over the network and to the host unencrypted*, so it is usually disabled by default for the Service.

Also check the Windows Remote Management event log (Microsoft-Windows-Windows Remote Management/Operational).

```
winrm get winrm/config
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = false        **
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2147483647
        MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647
```

Comment: Changing winrm config did not help unfortunately. Please see the question's update.

Comment: @Abid: `As there is no entry in Microsoft-Windows-Windows Remote Management/Operational on server side it looks like the request is blocked on client side.` This should be easily confirmed. You need to run a packet capture on the server to confirm if there is a connection, and if so what is in it. There should also be a second packet capture running concurrently on the client to perform a correlation. If the client isn't sending anything that simplifies things.

Comment: I ran a packet capture on client side where I noticed that the server *did respond* with a `401 Unauthorized`. So there was something wrong with the authentication. This leaded me to the solution. Thanks @Greg Askew!